# Linux ANSI C simultaneous access to files and locking

Tags: c, linux, file, locking

I am writing Linux ANSI C cgi-bin server program with simultaneous access to files.

1. Is it possible to distinguish between file existence and file locking?
   I can't find the answer with Google.
   I'd like to write a program which tries to open file for a few seconds if fd<0 
   (thinking that the file is locked for a while).
   But if the file does not exist it's fd also <0. So the program will waste time waiting.
2. Suppose a few threads try to append to the same file with no locking.
   One tries to add "AAAA", another - "BBBB".
   Can the result file be like "AABBAABB"? 
   Or it will always be like AAAABBBB or BBBBAAAA?
   Or the result is unpredictable?

Comment: You might want to look at flock(), http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock

Comment: Unfortunately there is no answer to distinguish lock and not existence. And flock does not work on NFS file system. I don't know which file system is on my servers.

Comment: Other things may not work on NFS as well, like ACL's.  If you have NFS you should consider something besides a mandatory lock, a lockfile is an example. Since you are using threads you will have to control concurrency with mutexes of pthread barriers or condition variables. Any of those also work to lock files.  Do not consider flock or ioctl with NFS as it is not guaranteed to work.  statvfs system call tells you the filesystem type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am assuming IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 might defer to the ISO C standard...

In case the fopen fails i.e. fd < 0 then the system sets some error codes...
you can check those error codes. In case of file non-existent, the returned error would be

ENOENT
A component of filename does not name an existing file or filename is an empty string.

For more reference visit:
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fopen.html

For point 2: I have been doing logging of certain data in my system by more than 100 processes writing to single file simultaneously but have never seen a merger of records(file is always opened in append mode). i.e. its always like AAAABBBB

Comment: okay. Thanks. It seems ENOENT can help to find out if file locked or not exists. If append works correctly, it seems it does not make sense to lock the file for append.